# What problem does liveData builder function solve?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

So there is a new builder function for `LiveData` which is:

```
val someLiveData = liveData {
    // do something
}
```

Can anyone explain exactly what this new builder function solve? How does it solve issues on rotation? How does it relate to webservice calls?

Any inputs would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To people voting for this thread to be close as "Too Broad" can anyone suggest how this topic could be broken down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone explain exactly what this new builder function solve?

The current [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata) on `liveData { }` it is pretty good and gives many examples. Here are some benefits you get for free by using it:

- **Automatic support for timeout** and canceling through the optional `timeoutInMs` (which defaults to 5 seconds).
- **No need to explicitly launch a coroutine** from an `init { }` block to initialize a `MutableLiveData<T>` (this hypothetical coroutine is referred to as `C` below).
- **No need to worry about what scope** to launch `C` in
- **No need to maintain code to wait with launching** `C` until it is actually needed (i.e. the `LiveData` has any registered and active observers).
- **No need to write code for relaunching** `C` when the LiveData is re-activated.

> How does it solve issues on rotation?

`LiveData` in itself does not solve any issue with preserving state across e.g. screen rotation. That's what `ViewModel` is for. Typically you have `LiveData` properties in your `ViewModel`. But there is not direct relationship between screen rotation problems and `liveData { }`

> How does it relate to webservice calls?

Since the block you pass to `liveData { }` is a suspend function, you can use coroutine support in your webservice. For example, **Retrofit 2.6.0** and later supports `suspend` modifiers in its HTTP request function definitions, which makes it very convenient to use in the `liveData { }` code block.